# Reduce space after figure and tables captions in templates provided by IEEE

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, captions

The usual answers provided for reducing space after figure and table captions are given for the default document classes such as 'article'. Solutions like putting the following in the preamble,

```
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup{belowskip=12pt,aboveskip=4pt}
```

of IEEE latex templates, however, does not work. The .tex and other style files provided by IEEE can be found [here](http://cvpr2021.thecvf.com/sites/default/files/2020-09/cvpr2021AuthorKit_2.zip). I do not wish to use `\vspace{}` for each caption.

Please suggest something.

Thankyou

Comment: If you currently write a paper that you intend to publish in one of the ieee journals, do not change their template.

Comment: Thanks. So you suggest using `\vspace` if at all required somewhere and not add a bit of code to preamble?

Comment: No, I suggest neither `\vspace` nor any redefinition of any kind. Stick to what the template gives you.